# Приоритет сетевых интерфейсов в Linux

Tags: linux, сеть

У меня на сервере есть два сетевых интерфейса, `tun0`(OpenVPN) и `ens2`(Интернет за NAT). Сейчас ситуация с сетью выглядит вот так:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.64.54.34     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens2
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.9        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.9        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.64.54.34     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.254 U     0      0        0 ens2
```

```
$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether de:1c:3c:57:a0:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.64.54.35/31 brd 10.64.54.35 scope global dynamic ens2
       valid_lft 84559sec preferred_lft 84559sec
    inet6 2001:bc8:47a0:1b11::1/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::dc1c:3cff:fe57:a012/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.10 peer 10.8.0.9/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7027:cbf7:1b3c:652b/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Я хочу поднять приоритет интерфейса tun0 выше ens2.
При выполнении команды `sudo ifmetric tun0 150` приоритет интерфейсов не меняется:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.64.54.34     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens2
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.9        255.255.255.0   UG    150    0        0 tun0
10.8.0.9        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    150    0        0 tun0
10.64.54.34     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.254 U     0      0        0 ens2
```

```
$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether de:1c:3c:57:a0:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.64.54.35/31 brd 10.64.54.35 scope global dynamic ens2
       valid_lft 84377sec preferred_lft 84377sec
    inet6 2001:bc8:47a0:1b11::1/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::dc1c:3cff:fe57:a012/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.10 peer 10.8.0.9/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7027:cbf7:1b3c:652b/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: что значит «поднять приоритет интерфейса»? метрика (величина обратныя некоему «приоритету») у тебя как раз изменилась, но т.к. маршруты ведут в разные сети на выбор она не влияет...

Comment: Я хочу чтобы при запросе на 10.8.0.X всегда выбирался интерфейс tun0

Comment: он и так всегда должен через него идти с такой таблицей...

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. А могу ли я сделать чтобы в ip addr show tun0 выводился выше ens2?

Comment: на вскидку — нет... хотя может какой-то хитрый способ и есть...

Comment: А если я скажу openvpn чтобы все пакеты через него ходили? Т.е. чтобы deinstantion было 0.0.0.0

Comment: нет, в `ip a` инерфейсы идут в порядке определяемом ядром… это ни на что не влияет и ни как не связано с маршрутами...

Comment: Жаль. Спасибо вам.

Comment: Это машина cloud провайдера, может они там чего-то накрутили

Comment: нет... всё нормально... это меня что-то вторые мысли взяли... при равной метрике выбирается маршрут с самой длинной маской...